# How can i solve: "Unable to resolve module..." in react-native using yarn workspaces?

Tags: react-native, babeljs, alias, yarn-workspaces

I am using react-native with yarn workspaces. Everthings works, but i can't get alias working. When i try to use:

```js
import { useTailwind } from 'tailwind'
```

i get the error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ../../../src/theme/useTailwind.tsx from /Users/.../packages/mobile-app/src/App.tsx
```

my folder structure looks like this:

```
 - root
   - packages
     - mobile-app
       - src
         - App.tsx
         - theme
           - useTailwind.tsx
```

my `metro.config.js` looks like this:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  projectRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false, // default true
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

and i configure the alias in `babel.config.js` like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": [
          "./src"
        ],
        "alias": {
          "tailwind": "./src/theme/useTailwind.tsx",
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

I tried to run the metro bundler with `yarn start --reset-cache` but it doesn't work. What do i need to change, to get the alias working?

Answer (score 0):

for all who have the same problem. I was able to solve the problem by changing the path as follows:

```
"alias": {
   "tailwind": "./packages/mobile-app/src/theme/useTailwind.tsx",
}
```